# hibernate envers 3.6 forRevisionsOfEntity returns Object instead MyEntity

Tags: hibernate, classcastexception, hibernate-envers

I querying the table_aud with the next query

```
public List<BitacoraControl> bitacoras(Long bitacoraControlId){
    AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(super.getEntityManager());
    AuditQuery  qry = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(BitacoraControl.class, false, true)
            .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(bitacoraControlId))
            .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().asc())
            ;

    return qry.getResultList();
    }
```

In my test case i try to iterate over the list.

```
List<BitacoraControl> bitacoras = auditDao.bitacoras(bitacoraControlId);//call may dao.

for(BitacoraControl bitacora : bitacoras ){
   log.debug("id: " + bitacora.getId);
}
```

An exception is thrown **java.lang.Object can not be cast to BitacoraControl**

Thank you.

Comment: I found my error, it turns out that i was using the wrong method. intead of **forRevisionsOfEntity** the method **forEntitiesAtRevision** must be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
AuditQuery  qry = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(BitacoraControl.class, true, true)
```

second *arg: selectEntitiesOnly* If true, instead of a list of three-element arrays, a list of entites will be returned as a result of executing this query.